# bash - obtener posición anterior de una busqueda hexadecimal

Tags: bash, shell-script, busqueda, hexadecimal

Estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda en hexadecimal de un patron.

Tengo un fichero y busco un patrón sobre el archivo en bash con...

```
xxd -g 2 -c 32 -u archivo | grep "0045 5804 0001 0000"
```

Esto me devuelve las lineas que contienen ese patrón.

```
FFFF FFFF FFFF 4556 4E54 0000 0116 0100 08B9 0045 5804 0001 0000 2008 0000 0001
```

Pero lo que yo quiero es que me devuelva los 4 dígitos anteriores a ese patrón.

En este caso el 08B9

¿Como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partiendo desde la linea y el patron:

```bash
linea="FFFF FFFF FFFF 4556 4E54 0000 0116 0100 08B9 0045 5804 0001 0000 2008 0000 0001"
patron="0045 5804 0001 0000"
```

Lo unico que debes hacer es entender estas 2 opciones que `grep` te brinda:

`grep -o`: Devuelve unicamente la coincidencia dentro de la linea.

```bash
echo $linea | grep -o "$patron"
$ 0045 5804 0001 0000
```

`grep -b`: Devuelve el numero de bytes de desplazamiento dependiendo de la linea que grep imprima y separa el **numero** de la **linea** con ":"

```bash
echo $linea | grep -b "$patron" 
$ 0:FFFF FFFF FFFF 4556 4E54 0000 0116 0100 08B9 0045 5804 0001 0000 2008 0000 0001
echo $linea | grep -ob "$patron"
$ 45:0045 5804 0001 0000
```

Ahora solamente podemos usar `cut` o `awk` para capturar el numero de bytes el cual representa el numero de bytes de la linea en donde el patron empieza:

```bash
echo $linea | grep -ob "$patron" | cut -d ":" -f 1
$ 45
echo $linea | grep -ob "$patron" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
$ 45
```

Una vez tienes el numero de bytes de desplazamiento usas el mecanismo de parameter expansion para capturar 4 caracteres, partiendo desde ese numero - 5. -5 por que existen 5 caracteres(incluyendo el espacio) antes del patron y quieres empezar ahi.

```bash
numero_de_bytes=$(echo $linea | grep -ob "$patron" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
echo ${linea:numero_de_bytes - 5: 4}
                |                 | 
                |                 |  
                |                 |
       empiezo en (45 - 5) = 40   |
       osea en el caracter "0"    |
                                  |
                       Me extiendo 4 caracteres
                          hacia la derecha
```

Y el resultado es:

```bash
$ 08B9
```

Espero haberme hecho entender.